# Expresión regular para diferentes caracteres en un split en java

Tags: java, regex, split

Tengo el texto de ejemplo `3x1+2x2-4x3` y la quiero picar donde este el `+` y el `-`, así que conseguí hacerlo por split.

```
String[] Ecuacion1 = Ecuacion.split("\\+");
```

pero sólo lo hace con el `+`.

¿Cómo consigo hacerlo con ambos, con el `-` y el `+`?

Comment: ¿Cual es el propósito de dividirlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el separador `|` para indicar que lo divida tomando como referencia una de las opciones, la otra opción o ambas (como si fuera un operador OR).

**Código**

```
String string = "3x1+2x2-4x3";
String[] Ecuacion1 = string.split("(\\+|\\-)");

for(int i = 0; i < Ecuacion1.length; i++){
  System.out.println(Ecuacion1[i]);
}
```

**Salida**

```
3x1
2x2
4x3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió

Comment: Y en caso de que desee separar incluyendo el + o -?
Por ejemplo tengo: -3x+4
Entonces quiero que en el arreglo se guarden los siguientes valores: arreglo[0] = -3x arreglo[1] = +4

Answer (score 5):

usa:

```
String[] Ecuacion1 = Ecuacion.split("[+-]");
```